# Is it possible to get the response code of the js imports in html programmatically?

Tags: javascript

In HTML, is it possible to see the response code of the script you imported?

I specifically need to get the response code of each script import. This has something to do with problem I'm dealing in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29641659/is-it-possible-to-intercept-html-css-and-js-files-used-in-angularjs?noredirect=1#comment47426865_29641659).

I was wondering if I couldn't intercept using angularjs maybe I can do it by using pure javascript.

Comment: Have you opened the console on chrome and checked the Network tab? Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Yes. but I need it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax would be the way to go. To cleanly replace a browser's request for at script file with a manual one in JS, you would need to do the following.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function(event) {

  // Check the http status code and inject script on page if 200

  if (event.target.status === 200) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerText = event.target.response;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
  else {

   // Handle other status codes..

  }
};
xhr.open('get', 'script.js', true);
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot intercept the response for resource requests made by the browser. The workaround would be to dynamically load the js files via ajax and check the result code there. E.g. (i'm using jquery syntax as its easier to write):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/js/my_js_file.js",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {            
        eval(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       // handle the response code
    }
});
```

This would be however cumbersome if you have may js files on your pages.

If your challenge is to detect whenever the user is authenticate or not, the solution can be simpler: you can make an ajax call at the beginning of the page to a /check_auth endpoint and if the endpoint returns 401, redirect the user to the login page.